# getting file path from HttpPostedFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the file path of an uploading file and i am using HttpPostedFile and it doesn't seem that it is an option to get the path name. Is that true? 
How can i go about this?

```
foreach (string s in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
                string fileExtension = "";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                    fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

                ....
            }
```

Comment: What does `file.FileName` give you ?

Comment: @AlaaMasoud i want to save a copy of the path of the file that is being uploaded. Is it possible to change the upload to use fileStream and that way it will be possible?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov `file.FileName` gives me `docName.doc` but i want `c:\temp\files\docName.doc`

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov could there possibly another route to do what i want? I need to get the path of the file being uploaded to store in the database

Comment: string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName); i think this statement give you path of the file.

Comment: @JeetBhatt that is what i thought too but when i debug i find that the path is: `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express\\Download.pdf` and it should be `C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\Download.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PKKG pointed out in a comment, this is not possible due to security restrictions by browsers.
They will only tell you the name of the uploaded file, not the path to it.

Also, for example, Google Chrome will give you a faked path when trying to grab it via javascript : `C:\fakepath\TestFile.xml`.

**EDIT:**
Now that I have `IE` at hand, I even realized that this **will** give you the full correct path via javascript if you grab the selected value, for example via `document.forms.file.value`.

This is IMO bad behaviour that you should not rely on. Browsers should hide this confidental data and you would probably be better off not trying to hack a solution that may work for a while, but it is not safe among different browsers or even versions.
Maybe the better question is, what are you trying to do with the client's full path anyway? There might be another approach without the need of the client's path.

Comment: is it possible to handle uploading files differently so i could possible get the path? FileStream?

Comment: @loop852 see my edit. bottom line is: there might be some workarounds for some versions of some browsers. But as browsers should not tell you the client's path, you should not try to "beat" the browser's security restrictions, as this might very well just break your code for future versions.

Comment: I am using this for homework submission so when when a student uploads their hw i am saving the path in which they have uploaded the file from. Basically used only in the database and not to be accessible in any way it is more like proof and if anything goes wrong with the file.

Comment: i am saving the filePath as part of the upload document information along with name, date, upload User, etc

Comment: Well, I am even unsure about if this is legally OK. The student might just upload the file from a path `C:\IAmAdopted\IHateMySchool\Homework.pdf`. This should generally be not of your interest and should also not even matter after the upload. Does it make any difference if they upload the file from desktop or from the root directory of a hard drive?

Comment: so, my honest advise would be to just drop that information. There will be little to no benefit by it, but the solution to get that information will be unmaintainable, unreliable and kind of a hack.